# d3 alter svg zoom behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am creating a graph representation of some arbitrary data, using d3 js. I need the graph to have two data representaion, depending on zoom level.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj9quqsd/1/) of where I am at the moment.

My zoomed in label representation needs fixed attributes, so how can set the scale to 1 when I am zoomed in? I tried creating a second zoom behavior and calling it, like this:

```
svg.call(zoomOutofLabel);
```

Basically i just want to be able to zoom in on nodes, when I am at maximum scale, change the representation, set the scale back to 1, and when i zoom out of that get the basic representation back on its own scale.

Comment: Can you explain it better, I think the question is not clear.

Comment: i have little dots representing the data, the data has position, name, etc. when i zoom in (for example to scale 4) i'd like to replace the dots with an svg group of objects to have better visual representation of the data, and when i zoom out of that i'd like to get back the dots.